# Pass object by reference to Node module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I cannot seem to pass an object by reference to a Node module. For example, in my main server.js, I have:

```
var test = {};
var ctrlFiles = require('./app/controllers/files')(test);
```

Further down in server.js, I intercept a HTTP request, and change the test object:

```
app.use(function(req, res){
    console.log('2. updating test');
    test.name = 'some value';
    next();
});
```

Even further down in server.js I define the route and pass the request to my files controller:

```
app.get('/files', function(req, res) {
    console.log('3. in files route, test is ', test);
    ctrlFiles.getUserFiles(req, res);
});
```

And the files controller is:

```
module.exports = function(testReference) {

    var test = testReference;

    console.log('1. test is ', test);

    return {

        getUserFiles: function(req, res) {

            console.log('4. in getUserFiles and test is ', test);

        }
    };
}
```

The logs looks like:

```
1. test is  {}
2. updating test
3. in files route, test is  { cookie: 
   { name: 'some value' }
4. in getUserFiles and test is  {}
```

`test` is always empty when I do a GET request to "/files". How do I pass `test` by reference so when it gets updated outside of my files controller, its updated within the controller too?

Comment: Are you sure that that first `.use()` callback is actually being invoked?

Comment: *Pass by reference* doesn't mean what you think it means. JavaScript is strictly pass by value. However, objects are represented *as* references. In your example you are certainly passing the same object everywhere. It would check whether the middleware part is actually executed, and in the right order.

Comment: @Pointy Yes im sure, i will update question

Comment: @FelixKling Yes the middleware is executed, will update

Comment: Apart from the issue your're having, DO NOT DO THIS. You're sharing a variables between multiple requests which means you end up with a race condition. If one of the middleware is async, a request may read a value which **another** request has set. Attach the value to the `req` object instead.

Comment: @Prinzhorn good point